# Android copyFile SDcard

Tags: android, sqlite

I have successfully imported the library "com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils" to export and import the database on the SD card. But in class I get error on line:`FileUtils.copyFile(internalDB, externalDB);`

```
File internalDB = new File("/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases/MyDatabase.db");
            File externalDB = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getPackageName()+"/database/MyDatabase.db");

                    try {
                        FileUtils.copyFile(internalDB, externalDB);
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(R.string.Toast_export), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        //toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(R.string.Toast_export_errore), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                            }
```

Comment: What is the error? Please show the full stack trace, preferably by using `Log.e()` instead of `e.printStackTrace()`. Also, please use `getDatabasePath()` rather than your incorrect semi-hardcoded path (will break on secondary accounts on Android 4.2+ tablets, among other possible scenarios). Also, please replace `getApplicationContext()` with `this`, as you do not need the `Application` to make a `Toast`.

Comment: Does your application have the required permissions?